# Sending email automatically from react native app using nodemailer when an action is done like after registering

Tags: react-native, nodemailer

I want to send an email from my react native app though nodemailer
I will be very grateful if someone could help me solve this problem.

There is also a video on it but there he has not disclosed how he has done it nor did he give the code.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeVthSN17Nk

Pls help me.

Comment: You need node.js to use nodemailer and also something like express.js for web server in order for your react native app to communicate with the backend

Comment: But if you see the video he did it with react native

Comment: yes but you don't see the code of the react native app, they are probably sending request to backend. edit: there is a backend running, you can see it on the terminal

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial for sending mail using node.js, express.js and nodemailer

https://medium.com/coox-tech/send-mail-using-node-js-express-js-with-nodemailer-93f4d62c83ee

Comment: how can i integrate it in react native app?

Comment: you need to have a separate backend running for the server then your react native app can send a post request to the server with the data to be sent in the mail. If you are not familiar with the backend subject, you should look into that first.

Comment: can you please send me an example on github or any links from where i can learn about backend?

Comment: Others pls answer